# Fetching Single Model from Laravel Collection

Tags: php, laravel, illuminate-container

Let's say you have an [Illuminate Collection](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.Collection.html) of `User` model objects.

```
$users = User::all();
```

Now, you want to get a single user from that collection by ID.

The only way I knew of doing this (super ugly):

```
$user_id = 22;
$user = $users->filter(function($user) use ($user_id) {
    return $user->id = $user_id;
})->first();
```

(Taken from [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931020/laravel-get-object-from-collection-by-attribute).)

However, if you do this, the `$users` collection is destroyed and unusable.  For instance, if there were 100 unique users in the collection before, you will instead now have 100 copies of the user with id `22` for some God forsaken reason.

How can I get a single user by ID from the collection without destroying the collection or looping through it?

I thought this would work...

```
$user_id = 22;
$temp_users = $users;
$user = $temp_users->filter(function($user) use ($user_id) {
    return $user->id = $user_id;
})->first();
```

But, even more infuriatingly, `$users` is still destroyed by the filter call - so evidently `$temp_users = $users` is identical to `$temp_users = &$users` or something.  There appears to be no way of duplicating a collection.

According to [this Github issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2341), Collection::filter() used to return brand new object instances.  Evidently, it doesn't anymore.  And neither does `$temp_users = $users;` I guess - which is confusing as hell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eloquent responses in the form of collections actually extend a special collection type located at `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`, which has a familiar method `find()`. Simply use that.

```
$users = User::all();

$jack = $users->find(22);
```

Comment: Thanks Cyode, but I'm afraid not.  That will simply return the 23rd element in the collection (basically array index), not the user with `id` of `22`.

Comment: No, it doesn't. [Check the source code for yourself.](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.php#L7-L26)

Comment: +1, No, it'll get the model with `id=22`, this is the right answer.

Comment: Guys, the `$key` in that source code refers to the array key in the `items` array.  Have a look at [this example collection](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=gdj3EQKi) - as you can clearly see, the model with a `$key` of `0` has an `id` of `1`.  If I had started with user id 44, then `$users->find(0)` will return the user with an `id` of `44`, *not* `0`.

Comment: In other words, `find()` and therefore `$key` have nothing to do with any of the attributes of the models, `id` or otherwise.

Comment: @Cyrode Yes, of course I've tried it.  In the collection I just gave you, `$users->find(1)` returns the user model with an `id` of `2`, because it is the 2nd model in the `items` array of the `$users` collection.

Comment: Something else is wonky with your code then. `find()` is the correct answer, works perfectly for me, and `$key` has *everything* to do with the **primary key** of the model when searching. So best of luck figuring that out.

Comment: Ah, tracing down the `getKey()` method in that code I can see that you are correct.  I apologize for my stubbornness; something indeed must be wonky in my code.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Probably would explain why my collection duplication attempts are bizarrely assigning by reference instead, too.

Comment: You assume that the primary_key in the User model is ID if it's not, find() will not work

Comment: @iosifv It should work regardless of your primary key column name. As long as you've configured the model appropriately, `Collection::find()` will use the correct name.

Answer (score 0):

In case ID is not your primary key, you could use firstWhere() like this:

```
$user_id = 22;
$userYouNeed = $users->firstWhere('id', $user_id);
```

If you would have a more complex condition you can consider using first() and providing your own callback with a condition like this

```
$user_id = 22;
$userYouNeed = $users->firs(function ($user) use ($user_id) {
    return $user->id === $user_id; // Or a more complex condition
});
```