# Laravel Advanced Wheres how to pass variable into function?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Example in doc:

```
DB::table('users')
        ->whereExists(function($query)
        {
            $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                  ->from('orders')
                  ->whereRaw('orders.user_id = users.id');
        })
        ->get();
```

But what if I need to use external variable like that:

```
            ->where('city_id', '=', $this->city->id)
            ->where(function($query)
                {
                    $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchQuery.'%')
                    ->orWhere('address', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchQuery.'%')

                })
```

For now I created new property and accessed it through `$this->`, but is there any more convenient way?

Answer (score 296, accepted):

You can pass the necessary variables from the parent scope into the closure with the `use` keyword.

For example:

```
DB::table('users')->where(function ($query) use ($activated) {
    $query->where('activated', '=', $activated);
})->get();
```

More on that [here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

#### EDIT (2019 update):

PHP 7.4 (will be released at [November 28, 2019](https://wiki.php.net/todo/php74)) introduces a shorter variation of the anonymous functions called [arrow functions](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arrow_functions_v2) which makes this a bit less verbose.

An example using PHP 7.4 which is functionally *nearly* equivalent (see the 3rd bullet point below):

```
DB::table('users')->where(fn($query) => $query->where('activated', '=', $activated))->get();
```

Differences compared to the regular syntax:

- `fn` keyword instead of `function`.
- No need to explicitly list all variables which should be captured from the parent scope - this is now done automatically by-value. See the lack of `use` keyword in the latter example.
- Arrow functions **always** return a value. This also means that it's impossible to use `void` return type when declaring them.
- The `return` keyword **must** be omitted.
- Arrow functions **must** have a single expression which is the return statement. Multi-line functions aren't supported at the moment. You can still chain methods though.

Comment: can we give name to fn($query) ? like if select from table ```from user as u```, I want to give name ```fn($query) as f```

Answer (score 24):

@kajetons' answer is fully functional.

You can also pass multiple variables by passing them like: `use($var1, $var2)`

```php
DB::table('users')->where(function ($query) use ($activated,$var2) {
    $query->where('activated', '=', $activated);
    $query->where('var2', '>', $var2);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Laravel eloquent you may try this as well.

```
$result = self::select('*')
                    ->with('user')
                    ->where('subscriptionPlan', function($query) use($activated){
                        $query->where('activated', '=', $roleId);
                    })
                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can pass variables using this...

```
$status =1;
 $info = JOBS::where(function($query) use ($status){        
         $query->where('status',$status);
         })->get();
print_r($info);
```