# Laravel Join : Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, join

I am trying to join two table. But it is giving an error "Trying to get property of non-object"... 
This is code in view page:

```
Asked by {{$user->name}}
```

In my controller I have code like this.

```
$user = DB::table('users')
                   ->join('question', function ($join) {
             $join ->on('question.id', '=', 'users.id')
                   ->where('question.ques_id' , '=', '$id');
    })
                   ->get();
```

I tried to do it like laravel documentation. Bust why this problem is arising?

Comment: The query must have failed therefore `$user` has not been set to anything and definitely not an object

Comment: I tried select. It didn't work. how I can set anything to $user? 

    $user = DB::table('users')
                    ->Join('question', function ($join) {
            $join->on('question.id', '=', 'users.id')
             ->where('question.ques_id' , '=', '$id');
        })
                    ->select('users.name')
                        ->get();

Comment: `Join` should be lowercase and `'$id'` without `''`. --- `$id` is also null, because it is in **anonymous function**. Try: `function($join) use ($id) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out the problem in join, did it in a alternative way.

```
 $question = DB::table('question')
                ->where('ques_id' , $id)
                ->first();
 $user = \App\User::find($question->id);
```

It was not satisfying but got the job done.

Answer (score 3):

`join` is name of method you should let it `lower-case` like [Laravel Document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#joins) (look at `Advanced Join Statements`)

```
$user = DB::table('users')
                   ->join('question', function ($join) {
              $join->on('question.id', '=', 'users.id')
                   ->where('question.ques_id' , '=', $id);
    })
                   ->get();
```

And btw `$id` is a `variable` you should leave it without `' '` or use `" "`

I think this work !

Comment: your correction is right but now it is giving an error "Undefined variable: id". I tried passing $id as argument and failed. 
$id is used on upper segment of the code without any error.

Comment: `$id` is an `variable`, where do you set value for this `variable`. Can you show more  code ?

Comment: @DhrubaChakraborty http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548073/laravel-advanced-wheres-how-to-pass-variable-into-function

I found it :D for anonymous function

Comment: yes, now argument passed but still that problem "Trying to get property of non-object". :(
     $user = DB::table('users')
                   ->join('question', function ($join)  use ($id) {
              $join->on('question.id', '=', 'users.id')
                   ->where('question.ques_id' , '=', $id);
    })
                   ->get();

Comment: @DhrubaChakraborty can you `dd` the `$user` for me please ?

Comment: This way `$user` will be an array of objects. You need to use `->first()` before `->get()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple join:

```php
$user = DB::table('users')
    ->join('question', 'question.id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->where('question.ques_id' , '=', $id);
    ->first()
    ->get();
```

But if you want to keep things simple, you should propper define your entities (`User` and `Question`) with their relations:

```php
Class Question extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'question';
    protected $primaryKey = 'ques_id';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

And keep the controller code simple:

```php
$user = Question::find($id)->user;
```

**Note:**
You should give things proper names. When i see `question.id` i think it's the ID of the question (not user).