# Laravel query with having 'where' and 'orwhere' not working properly

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I've the below function -

```
public function search_profile(Request $request)
{
    $search_keyword = $request->search;
    $search_user = $request->user;
    $user_public = User::where('username', $request->user)->first();

    $tags_list = Tag::orderBy('tag', 'asc')->get();
    $bookmarks = Bookmark::orderBy('created_at','desc')->where('bookmarker', $search_user)->where('public', '1')->where('tags', 'rlike', $search_keyword)->orwhere('title', 'rlike', $search_keyword)->orwhere('description', 'rlike', $search_keyword)->orwhere('contents', 'rlike', $search_keyword)->paginate(15);
    $bookmarks_all = Bookmark::orderBy('created_at','desc')->where('bookmarker', $search_user)->where('public', '1')->where('tags', 'rlike', $search_keyword)->orwhere('title', 'rlike', $search_keyword)->orwhere('description', 'rlike', $search_keyword)->orwhere('contents', 'rlike', $search_keyword)->get();
    return view('profile_search')->with('bookmark', $bookmarks)->with('tags_list', $tags_list)->with('bookmarks_all', $bookmarks_all)->with('username', $user_public)->with('search_keyword', $search_keyword);
}
```

But I'm getting results even from other `bookmarker`. For example - If `$search_keyword = 'laravel'` and `$serach_user = 'zack'`. I'm getting results from other users as well.

I'm new on laravel. So What I'm doing wrong in the queries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your query

```
$bookmarks = Bookmark::orderBy('created_at','desc')->where('bookmarker', $search_user)->where('public', '1')->where('tags', 'rlike', $search_keyword)->orwhere('title', 'rlike', $search_keyword)->orwhere('description', 'rlike', $search_keyword)->orwhere('contents', 'rlike', $search_keyword)->paginate(15);
```

will yield you something like this

```
SELECT * FROM bookmarks WHERE bookmarker = $search_user AND public = 1 OR title rlike $search_keyword OR content rlike $search_keyword;
```

Which is not what you intended since if it matches the title, it will return the result.

What you most likely want is this:

```
Bookmark::orderBy('created_at','desc')
        ->where('bookmarker', '$search_user')
        ->where('public', '1')
        ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($search_keyword) {
            $query->where('title', 'rlike', $search_keyword)
                  ->where('contents', 'rlike', $search_keyword);
        })
        ->get();
```

Check out the [advance where](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#advanced-where-clauses).

Comment: getting `Undefined variable: search_keyword` error! why it cannot access the variable?

Comment: oops you have to use the Use keyword -> https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php, answer updated

Comment: I just found about it here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29548311/3866364

Answer (score 0):

hey Xahed Kamal please use this query with a table like here

```
$data =  DB::table('table_name')->where('column_name',abcd)->orWhere('column_name',abcd)->get();
```

it's working fine

and next one

```
$bookmarks = Bookmark::orderBy('created_at','desc')->where('bookmarker', $search_user)->where('public', '1')->where('tags', 'rlike', $search_keyword)->pluck('id');


$bookmarks_data = Bookmark::whereIn('id',$bookmarks)->orwhere('title', 'rlike', $search_keyword)->orwhere('description', 'rlike', $search_keyword)->orwhere('contents', 'rlike', $search_keyword)->paginate(15);
```