# Laravel 5.2 passing variable to query builder

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I will love to use query builder to obtain the email address of users from the database and send emails to them all, but so far i have been stuck on this for days now.

public function postSearchAction(Request $request){

```
      $data = array(
            'service' =>  $request->get('service'),
            'location' => $request->get('location'),
            'allProviders' => $request->get('allProviders'),
            'date' => $request->get('date'),
            'optional_skills' => $request->get('optional_skills'),
            'landmark_homepage' => $request->get('landmark_homepage'),
            'name' => Auth::user()->name,
            'userEmail' => Auth::user()->email,
            'requesterMobile' => Auth::user()->phone_number
        );




         $email = DB::table('users')->where('main_service', 'LIKE', '%'.$data['location'].'%')
            ->where('city_service', 'LIKE', '%'.$data['location'].'%')
            ->pluck('email');




      To send emails

        \Mail::send('auth.emails.serviceProviders', $data, function($message) use ($data)
        {
                $message->to($email, 'oluyemi')->subject('Test');
        });


    }
```

Now i have tried to use dd($mail) but the method returned an empty array.
I think its worth mentioning that i once i change the variable within the query builder to the expected value, everything works fine.

Someone should please help, dont know what am doing wrong. I really need to use the variables.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure `$data['location']` has a value? Are there any errors?

Comment: @timenomad thanks for your response..... yes it does, if i do dd($data['location']) it returns the value. dd($email) returns []

Comment: $email = DB::table('users')->where('main_service', 'LIKE', '%'.$data['service'].'%')
                ->where('city_service', 'LIKE', '%'.$data['location'].'%')
                ->pluck('email');

Comment: Check this link for the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548073/laravel-advanced-wheres-how-to-pass-variable-into-function

Answer (score 0):

Please show us the raw SQL query so we can see what's wrong.
After the $email query, put:

```
DB::enableQueryLog();  
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

It will be the last item.

OR

Add `->toSql()` instead of `->pluck()` and dd() it.

Comment: i just tried this     $email = DB::table('users')->where('main_service', 'LIKE', '%'.$data['service'].'%')
                ->where('city_service', 'LIKE', '%'.$data['location'].'%')
                ->tosql(); 
            dd($email);. And got                                                           "select * from `users` where `main_service` LIKE ? and `city_service` LIKE ?"

Comment: Note that it's toSql (capitalized S). Can you post the output?