# Laravel 5 Variable Constructed Query String Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am trying to take JSON sent to my Laravel server and return the results of an Eloquent query string which is itself constructed based on the JSON that is being sent. I plan to chain together multiple `where`/`whereHas` statements to achieve this, but so far I am stuck on the first and wondering if this is possible.

**Code:**

```
if(isset($settings->new)){
$assetQuery = "where('created_at','>',".Carbon::now()->subMonths(1).")";
}
if(isset($settings->long)){
$assetQuery = "where('lengthD','Long')";
}
if(isset($settings->short)){
$assetQuery = "where('lengthD','Short')";
}
if(!isset($settings->new)&&!isset($settings->long)&&!isset($settings->short)){
$assetQuery = "where('id','>',0)";
}
$batch = MyModel::whereHas('asset',function ($query) use ($assetQuery){return $query->$assetQuery;})
->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(20)->get();
```

`$settings` is a `json_decode` representation of my JSON. It will only have one instruction where in comes to the `$assetQuery`. As you can see, if it fails to have any of these instructions it will pick all of them (`where('id','>',0)`).

My issue is I can't seem to append the `$assetQuery` string to the `$batch` Eloquent line. How can I do this so I can string together variable queries?

I did see this: [Laravel Advanced Wheres how to pass variable into function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548073/laravel-advanced-wheres-how-to-pass-variable-into-function)

But in that case the variable was being used in one very small section of the query, not for the whole query string. Maybe I need to move my conditionals within the `function ($query)` function?

Comment: Why are you formatting the query functions as strings?

Comment: @JimWright I didn't realize I had a better option!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on exactly what you're asking, but I think the following will work for you.

```
$batch = MyModel::whereHas('asset', function ($query) use ($settings){
    if(isset($settings->new)){
        $query->where('created_at','>',Carbon::now()->subMonths(1));
    }
    if(isset($settings->long)){
        $query->where('lengthD','Long');
    }
    if(isset($settings->short)){
        $query->where('lengthD','Short');
    }
    if(!isset($settings->new)&&!isset($settings->long)&&!isset($settings->short)){
        $query->where('id','>',0);
    }
})->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(20)->get();
```