# combining when() and whereBetween() methods in laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Model in Larevel that is taking in parameters for reporting total units in the database.

I want to be able to filter the units returned based on the `$entity_ids` and the `$start` and `$end` dates selected by the user.

`entity_ids` is working fine with a simple `whereIn()` method call, but the dates are causing some issue.

My code in `Order.php` Model is below:

```
public static function getAllOrdersForReporting($entity_ids, $start, $end) {
    $orders = Order::select('all order information entered here')
    ->whereIn('orders.entity_id', $entity_ids)
    ->when($start && $end, function ($query, $start, $end) { //<-- Error Thrown Here
        return $query->whereBetween('order_date', [$start, $end]);
    })
    ->join('entities', 'entities.id', '=', 'ura_orders.entity_id')
    ->join('entity_address_information', 'entity_address_information.entity_id', '=', 'ura_orders.entity_id')->distinct()->get();

    return $orders;
}
```

In my `ReportingController.php` I am entering in the following:

```
public function displayUnits() {
    $entities = request()->entities_ids;
    $start = request()->start_date;
    $end = request()->end_date;
    $orders = Ura_order::getAllOrdersForReporting($entities, $start, $end);

    return view('reporting.pages.units', compact('entities', 'start', 'end', 'orders'));
}
```

However when I run this, I get the following error:

> Too few arguments to function
>   App\Models\Order::App\Models{closure}(), 2 passed in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Concerns\BuildsQueries.php
>   on line 91 and exactly 3 expected

Not exactly sure what this error means, except that the `Model` is seeing only 2 errors passed in and it expected 3.

I marked the line where it is throwing the error up above in the code.

Any advice on how to get this to work? I know the 3rd parameter for `when()` is supposed to be a callback function, but not sure how to make this work.

Comment: Per [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries), the third parameter of a `when` call is supposed to be a function. `$end` is not a function.

Comment: Yeah I know that and I should have been more clear in the question, I'm looking for how to make the functionality I'm seeking work, and the 3rd parameter callback function I'm not sure if it's going to return that.

Comment: take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548073/laravel-advanced-wheres-how-to-pass-variable-into-function) topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this code:

```php
->when($start && $end, function ($query, $condition) use($start, $end) { 
        return $query->whereBetween('order_date', [$start, $end]);
    })
```

As already pointed in the comments the tihrd parameter of a `when()` should be a `function`, with the `use()` statement you can pass the variables in the closure.

Comment: This worked, but you did not need the $condition variable passed into the function.

Comment: You're right it's not needed, but can be useful for others with similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have to `use` variables in your callback function:

```
->when($start && $end, function ($query) use ($start, $end) {
    return $query->whereBetween('order_date', [$start, $end]);
})
```