# How to pass two forms as parameter to laravel controller?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, laravel-5.4

**Laravel controller code:**

```
public function addPriceDetails(Request $priceform,$dataId)
{
$priceInfo = new priceInfo ;
$priceInfo->deviceCategoryId=$dataId;
$priceInfo->productId=$this->getproductId();
$priceInfo->SKUID=$priceform->input('skuid');
$priceInfo->productName=$priceform->input('productName');
$priceInfo->listingStatus =$priceform->input('listingStatus');
$priceInfo->MRP =$priceform->input('mrp');
$priceInfo->sellingPrice=$priceform->input('selprice');
$priceInfo->fulfillmentBy =$priceform->input('fulfillment');
$priceInfo->procurementType =$priceform->input('procurementType');
$priceInfo->procurementSLA =$priceform->input('sla');
$priceInfo->stock =$priceform->input('stock');
$priceInfo->localDelCharge =$priceform->input('local');
$priceInfo->zonalDelCharge =$priceform->input('zonal');
$priceInfo->nationalDelCharge=$priceform->input('national');
$priceInfo->packWeight =$priceform->input('weight');
$priceInfo->packLength =$priceform->input('length');
$priceInfo->packBreadth =$priceform->input('breadth');
$priceInfo->packHeight =$priceform->input('height');
$priceInfo->HSN =$priceform->input('hsn');
$priceInfo->save();

return response()->json([
    'SKUID'    => $priceInfo->SKUID,
    'listingStatus' => $priceInfo->listingStatus,
    'MRP' => $priceInfo->MRP,
    'sellingPrice' => $priceInfo->sellingPrice
]);
}
```

This is my function to add the values for one of the forms.

controller code for second form:

```
  public function addProductDetails(Request $formdescription,$dataId)
  {
   $description=new productDescription;
   $description->deviceCategoryId=$dataId;
   $description->productDescriptionId=$this-
   >getproductDescriptionId();
   $description->modelName=$formdescription->input('mname');
   $description->Height=$formdescription->input('height');
   $description->Weight=$formdescription->input('weight');
   $description->Depth=$formdescription->input('depth');
   $description->Width =$formdescription->input('width');
   $description->Type =$formdescription->input('type');
   $description->Character=$formdescription->input('character');
   $description->batteryType=$formdescription->input('batteryType');
   $description->salesPackage =$formdescription->input('package');
   $description->skillSet =$formdescription->input('skillSet');
   $description->Colour=$formdescription->input('colour');
   $description->Material =$formdescription->input('material');
   $description->maxAge=$formdescription->input('maxage');
   $description->minAge =$formdescription->input('minage');
   $description->batteryNos =$formdescription->input('batteryNos');
   $description->batteryOperated=$formdescription-
   >input('batteryOperated');
  $description->rechargable=$formdescription->input('rechargable');

   $description->save();



 return response()->json([
    'modelName'    => $formdescription->mname,
    'colour' => $formdescription->colour,
    'rechargable' => $formdescription->rechargable,
    'batteryType' => $formdescription->batteryType
]);

 $description->product()->associate($priceInfo);
}
```

This is my another function for adding another form values. But here I am using product_Id value is a foreign key value and **I need to get this with before added form.I don't know how to get this.** **Or else it is helpful if I  pass both the form values in a single function.**

**Script Code:**

```
    <script src = 
   "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function () {

   $("#priceSave").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form1 = $('#priceform').serialize();
   //alert(form1);
   $.ajax({
    url:'addPriceDetails/{{$dataId}}',
    type: "get",
    data: form1,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      //alert(response.SKUID);
        $("#skuid").append(response.SKUID); 
        $("#mrp").append(response.MRP);       
        $("#lstatus").append(response.listingStatus); 
        $("#selprice").append(response.sellingPrice); 
      }
      });
      });



  $("#descSave").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var form2 = $('#formdescription').serialize();
   alert(form2);
   $.ajax({
     url:'addProductDetails/{{$dataId}}',
    type: "get",
    data: form2,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      //alert(response);
        $("#batterytype").append(response.batteryType); 
        $("#modelname").append(response.modelName);    
        $("#colour").append(response.colour); 
       // $("#colour").append(response.Colour); 
        $("#rechargable").append(response.rechargable); 
        //alert(response.Material);
        //alert(response.salesPackage);
      }
     });
     });


     });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
return response()->json([
  'SKUID' => $priceInfo->SKUID,
  'listingStatus' => $priceInfo->listingStatus,
  'MRP' => $priceInfo->MRP,
  'sellingPrice' => $priceInfo->sellingPrice,
  'id' =>$this->getproductId()
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert a new product details into database you can get the inserted product id. just write the statement after save `$productID = $description->id;`

Comment: hellooo..anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Caches your objects and their values. I am assuming that you have defined the relations with the product details and price details. Just pass the $product->description()->save($productInfo);
and soon after $product->pricing()->save($description);

for this you must have two functions in the product model named description() and pricing() they will define their relationship with the product. Its as easy as eating meal. Also define a fillables array what you are doing is much weird.

Comment: public function product(){

      return $this->belongsTo(priceInfo::class);
  }

Comment: public function productDetails()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(priceInfo::class);

 }

Comment: These are the relationships defined between pricedetails and product description

Comment: Have you tried using these functions the way $product->relation-name()->save($the-related-variable)  ???

Comment: No,I had some confusions with your variable namings

Comment: Will you please make it clear with the help of my relationships and variable namings

Comment: see try saving the data like

Comment: You have given the wrong relationship. See a product class product(){} have many details and priceinfo belongs to product so don't define productPricing as product()

Comment: define product() as productPricing

Comment: then first save the product or get the product object by id whome details are you going to save. then $product->productPricing()-save($priceInfo);
soon after $product->productDetails()->save($description);

Comment: Made the changes,but throws undefined variable:product error

Comment: Brother i''ve said first find the product object its a simple way do you have product id ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931020/laravel-get-object-from-collection-by-attribute

Comment: for reference get the $product object this way

Comment: and then add the related elements

Comment: Sorry, how I don't want any specific field product Id values...I needed those Id which is referred as foreign key

Comment: brother you don't just you need what is to fetch that object from database like 
$product=DB::table('your-table')->where("id","=",$id-of-current-record);
or if you are previously adding a product and then adding its detail 
$product=DB::table('your-table')->where("id","=",DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId());

Comment: all other stuff of relating the fields will be done by the laravel it self he will automatically insert the id's

Comment: Ok,I ll do the changes